# Job Submission failed with exception 'org.apache.hadoop.util.DiskChecker$DiskErrorException(No space available in any of the local directories.)'

Tags: hadoop, hive

I am getting below error when i ran hive query.  Please help me to resolve this issue.

HIVE> insert overwrite table bucket_emp1 select * from emp;

Query ID = hduser_20160426213038_58cbf1dc-a345-40f8-ab3d-a3258046b279
Total jobs = 3
Launching Job 1 out of 3
Number of reduce tasks is set to 0 since there's no reduce operator
org.apache.hadoop.util.DiskChecker$DiskErrorException: No space available in any of the local directories.
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.LocalDirAllocator$AllocatorPerContext.getLocalPathForWrite(LocalDirAllocator.java:366)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.LocalDirAllocator.getLocalPathForWrite(LocalDirAllocator.java:150)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.LocalDirAllocator.getLocalPathForWrite(LocalDirAllocator.java:131)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.LocalDirAllocator.getLocalPathForWrite(LocalDirAllocator.java:115)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalDistributedCacheManager.setup(LocalDistributedCacheManager.java:131)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.(LocalJobRunner.java:163)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner.submitJob(LocalJobRunner.java:731)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.submitJobInternal(JobSubmitter.java:536)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1296)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1293)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1628)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:1293)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$1.run(JobClient.java:562)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$1.run(JobClient.java:557)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1628)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJobInternal(JobClient.java:557)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJob(JobClient.java:548)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.ExecDriver.execute(ExecDriver.java:431)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.MapRedTask.execute(MapRedTask.java:137)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Task.executeTask(Task.java:160)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.TaskRunner.runSequential(TaskRunner.java:88)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.launchTask(Driver.java:1653)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.execute(Driver.java:1412)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.runInternal(Driver.java:1195)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:1059)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:1049)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLocalCmd(CliDriver.java:213)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processCmd(CliDriver.java:165)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLine(CliDriver.java:376)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.executeDriver(CliDriver.java:736)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.run(CliDriver.java:681)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.main(CliDriver.java:621)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:221)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)
Job Submission failed with exception 'org.apache.hadoop.util.DiskChecker$DiskErrorException(No space available in any of the local directories.)'
FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.MapRedTask

Comment: It says: "No space available in any of the local directories". What else do you need?

Answer (score 0):

Map Reduce framework looks for the directories specified by `mapreduce.cluster.local.dir` parameter during processing of your job and after that it verifies if there is enough space on the directories or not, so that it can create the intermediate files for it.

Map Reduce job will fail if there is no required space available for your directory and report with the error shared by you.

Ensure that there is enough space on the local directories.

It's better to compress (like `Gzip compression`) the intermediate output files so that it will take less space during processing.

```
conf.set(“mapred.compress.map.output”, “true”)
conf.set(“mapred.output.compression.type”, “BLOCK”);
conf.set(“mapred.map.output.compression.codec”, “org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.GzipCodec”);
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Please tell me how to increase space should i delete some data from my file system or is there any process to increase space. my hard disk total size is 200 GB free.